# Referencing files in JavaScript in WordPress Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, javascript

I have a JavaScript file in my plugin in which I need to reference a sound file to play when any link is clicked in any front end page.

I did it like this:

my_plugin/my_plugin.php

```
function pr_add_link_sound () {
  wp_register_script('add_sound', plugins_url('add_sound.js', __FILE__), ['jquery'], '', true);
  wp_enqueue_script('add_sound');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pr_add_link_sound');
```

my_plugin/add_sound.js

```
(function($){
  var sound = new Audio('sound.mp3');
  $('a').on('click', function(){
    sound.play();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

I added the 'sound.mp3' file in the root folder of my plugin like this:

my_plugin/sound.mp3

But the reference of the sound file in the js script is incorrect. How should I refer to the file correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `wp_localize_script`.

```
function pr_add_link_sound () {

//Register the script first
wp_register_script('add_sound', plugins_url( 'add_sound.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '', true);

//Localize the sound file url to use in the script
$args = array(
    'sound1' => plugins_url( 'sound.mp3', __FILE__ ),
);
wp_localize_script( 'add_sound', 'PRSound', $args );

//Enqueue the script
wp_enqueue_script('add_sound');

}
```

You can reference the sound in the js file like this..

```
(function($){
  var sound = new Audio( PRSound.sound1 );
  $('a').on('click', function(){
    sound.play();
  });
})(jQuery);
```